# Apache Beam: Kafka consumer restarted over and over again

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam, apache-pulsar

I have this very simple Beam Pipeline that reads records from a Kafka Topic and writes them to a Pulsar Topic:

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

p.apply(
  KafkaIO.<Long, String>read()
    .withTopic("<topic>")
    .withBootstrapServers("<url>")
    .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
    .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
    .updateConsumerProperties(getConsumerProps())
    .withoutMetadata() // PCollection<KV<Long, String>>
)
  .apply(Values.<String>create())
  .apply(ParDo.of(new PulsarSink()));

p.run();
```

From my understanding this should create exactly one Kafka Consumer that pushes it's values down the Pipeline. Now for some reason the Pipeline seems to restart over and over again creating multiple Kafka Consumers and multiple Pulsar Producers.

Here is an excerpt from the logs that show multiple Kafka Consumers being created:

```
2019-06-07 16:08:30,010 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [<url>:39701, <url>:39702, <url>:39703]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = 292330999892453
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 524288
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-256
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

2019-06-07 16:08:30,097 INFO  o.a.k.c.s.a.AbstractLogin - Successfully logged in.
2019-06-07 16:08:30,204 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 2.1.0
2019-06-07 16:08:30,205 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : eec43959745f444f
2019-06-07 16:08:30,684 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Cluster ID: AKrCWqWfQKOfb9OSgwFyIQ
2019-06-07 16:08:30,693 INFO  o.a.b.s.i.kafka.KafkaUnboundedSource - Partitions assigned to split 0 (total 1): 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-0
2019-06-07 16:08:30,693 INFO  o.a.b.s.i.kafka.KafkaUnboundedSource - Partitions assigned to split 1 (total 1): 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-1
2019-06-07 16:08:30,693 INFO  o.a.b.s.i.kafka.KafkaUnboundedSource - Partitions assigned to split 2 (total 1): 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-2
2019-06-07 16:08:30,720 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [<url>:39701, <url>:39702, <url>:39703]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = 292330999892453
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 524288
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-256
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

2019-06-07 16:08:30,720 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [<url>:39701, <url>:39702, <url>:39703]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = 292330999892453
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 524288
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-256
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

2019-06-07 16:08:30,720 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [<url>:39701, <url>:39702, <url>:39703]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = 292330999892453
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 524288
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-256
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

2019-06-07 16:08:30,721 INFO  o.a.k.c.s.a.AbstractLogin - Successfully logged in.
2019-06-07 16:08:30,734 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 2.1.0
2019-06-07 16:08:30,734 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : eec43959745f444f
2019-06-07 16:08:30,742 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 2.1.0
2019-06-07 16:08:30,742 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : eec43959745f444f
2019-06-07 16:08:30,743 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 2.1.0
2019-06-07 16:08:30,743 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : eec43959745f444f
2019-06-07 16:08:31,116 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Cluster ID: AKrCWqWfQKOfb9OSgwFyIQ
2019-06-07 16:08:31,117 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=292330999892453] Discovered group coordinator <url>:39703 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2019-06-07 16:08:31,145 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Cluster ID: AKrCWqWfQKOfb9OSgwFyIQ
2019-06-07 16:08:31,145 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=292330999892453] Discovered group coordinator <url>:39703 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2019-06-07 16:08:31,147 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Cluster ID: AKrCWqWfQKOfb9OSgwFyIQ
2019-06-07 16:08:31,148 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=292330999892453] Discovered group coordinator <url>:39703 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2019-06-07 16:08:31,351 INFO  o.a.b.s.i.kafka.KafkaUnboundedSource - Reader-0: reading from 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-0 starting at offset 318186186
2019-06-07 16:08:31,352 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [<url>:39701, <url>:39702, <url>:39703]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = Reader-0_offset_consumer_1189437256_292330999892453
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 524288
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-256
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

2019-06-07 16:08:31,359 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 2.1.0
2019-06-07 16:08:31,359 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : eec43959745f444f
2019-06-07 16:08:31,389 INFO  o.a.b.s.i.kafka.KafkaUnboundedSource - Reader-1: reading from 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-1 starting at offset 318738731
2019-06-07 16:08:31,389 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [<url>:39701, <url>:39702, <url>:39703]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = Reader-1_offset_consumer_1231768376_292330999892453
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 524288
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-256
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

2019-06-07 16:08:31,394 INFO  o.a.b.s.i.kafka.KafkaUnboundedSource - Reader-2: reading from 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-2 starting at offset 318129714
2019-06-07 16:08:31,394 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [<url>:39701, <url>:39702, <url>:39703]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = Reader-2_offset_consumer_64443017_292330999892453
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 524288
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-256
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

2019-06-07 16:08:31,395 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 2.1.0
2019-06-07 16:08:31,395 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : eec43959745f444f
2019-06-07 16:08:31,397 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 2.1.0
2019-06-07 16:08:31,398 INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : eec43959745f444f
2019-06-07 16:08:31,613 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=292330999892453] Fetch offset 318129714 is out of range for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-2, resetting offset
2019-06-07 16:08:31,613 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=292330999892453] Fetch offset 318186186 is out of range for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-0, resetting offset
2019-06-07 16:08:31,641 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=292330999892453] Resetting offset for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-2 to offset 320367573.
2019-06-07 16:08:31,641 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=292330999892453] Resetting offset for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-0 to offset 321301099.
2019-06-07 16:08:31,648 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Cluster ID: AKrCWqWfQKOfb9OSgwFyIQ
2019-06-07 16:08:31,649 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=292330999892453] Fetch offset 318738731 is out of range for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-1, resetting offset
2019-06-07 16:08:31,667 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Cluster ID: AKrCWqWfQKOfb9OSgwFyIQ
2019-06-07 16:08:31,672 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=292330999892453] Resetting offset for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-1 to offset 320867070.
2019-06-07 16:08:31,714 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Cluster ID: AKrCWqWfQKOfb9OSgwFyIQ
2019-06-07 16:08:31,860 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1189437256_292330999892453] Resetting offset for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-0 to offset 336281187.
2019-06-07 16:08:31,885 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1189437256_292330999892453] Resetting offset for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-0 to offset 336281187.
2019-06-07 16:08:31,905 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=Reader-1_offset_consumer_1231768376_292330999892453] Resetting offset for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-1 to offset 336474159.
2019-06-07 16:08:31,938 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=Reader-1_offset_consumer_1231768376_292330999892453] Resetting offset for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-1 to offset 336474159.
2019-06-07 16:08:31,957 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=Reader-2_offset_consumer_64443017_292330999892453] Resetting offset for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-2 to offset 336295646.
2019-06-07 16:08:31,981 INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=Reader-2_offset_consumer_64443017_292330999892453] Resetting offset for partition 292330999892453.events.all.v1.json-2 to offset 336295646.
2019-06-07 16:08:32,142 INFO  o.a.b.s.i.kafka.KafkaUnboundedSource - Reader-0: first record offset 321301099
```

Why are Kafka Consumers being restarted over and over again? Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I might be wrong, but i don't think the consumer is restarting, I think that the kafka consumer starts internally one consumer per broker, as far as i see that you have 3 brokers. But I don't know exactly, or this is a little piece of the log, that prints this over and over again?

Comment: @Ramonjansengomez yes this log prints over and over again. See https://gist.github.com/rfuerst87/bf023f3e31e7051ff5551b0dfc957dc2 for a more detailed log (I had to shorten it here because of the character limit). You will also notice the logs from pulsar, which tells me `PulsarSink` is initialized multiple times too.

Comment: @Roman did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: @AnandSinghKunwar Not really. What I found IIRC is that Beam Direct Runner has a built in method to force a Pipeline to restart. Guess that's to ensure robustness for other runners. I switched then to a local Flink Runner which worked as expected. Direct Runner seems to be designed for testing purposes only. Eventually I abandoned Beam as it was an overkill for the Project I was working on. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary purpose of the DirectRunner is local testing of Pipelines. As such, it exhibits behavior, that might be suboptimal performance-wise. One example might be that it purposefully serializes and deserializes data between operators, even though it is not necessary. The reason is to validate that the application code does not modify the input object, which is forbidden in Beam. The reason why there are many consumers being created is another example of this - DirectRunner performs a checkpoint (including many possibly unnecessary steps, like re-creating the consumer), very often - see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/06dbe4f59592efcf0c68c943281987819588ce87/runners/direct-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/direct/SplittableProcessElementsEvaluatorFactory.java#L178).

As such, DirectRunner really should be used only in tests and/or moderate conditions, where performance is not a concern. When performance is a concern, a different runner should be used - either some distributed, or local version of such runner - e.g. local FlinkRunner.

Comment: Totally forgot about this question. Thanks for providing an answer!